# Replication in Memgraph

Tags: graph-databases, memgraphdb

I'm familiar with replication from other systems and I've read the docs about sync, async and semi-sync replication in Memgraph. What I'm most interested in is the why: what benefits do we get from replication? Disaster recovery, high availability, parallel processing, etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get multiple things. Basically, replication makes your data redundant. It copies it to multiple machines and achieves multiple benefits with it.

The queries you are executing on your database can be performed on any machine that could contain that data, it, therefore, provides a higher throughput on your read queries. On the other hand, if one machine goes down, others can compensate for it with the same data since it is replicated. So all of the things you said are true